# Fade Div out and fade next div and animate child element within

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 divs i want to fade in, then out and once they have faded in, have the child element animate its way up, so it comes in from the bottom right.

Ive made the following but cant seem to get any further, has anybody got at ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/FeqkB/2/

Comment: Being each one on top of each other is ok? Or did you screw up the layout?

Comment: I screwed up the layout, they shouldnt be on top of each other, should be display:none then block after an interval...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this http://jsfiddle.net/FeqkB/5/

try this updates

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FeqkB/8/)

Comment: This is similar to what im looking for @Kamal, but is there a way for the child 'img' element to animate in once the div is in view?